openpyxl particle size distribution linechart

How can I plot such a graph using openpyxl?
X axis should be in log, Y axis in linear. I also want to keep 1, 10, 100, 1000 and 10000 in the X-axis as constant axis tick labels.
I tried using a data table, however, all recognised as y data but not x data. I tried to make series, that didn't work neither.

What have you tried so far?

What you show is not a line chart, but a scatter chart. Line charts are category charts having categories on x axis. For category charts, the x-axis cannot be scaled logarithmic.
Based on the example from Scatter Charts:
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
    ['Size', 'Ser 1', 'Ser 2'],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [50, 3, 3],
    [200, 30, 50],
    [1000, 40, 60],
    [2000, 95, 95],
    [5000, 98, 98],
    [10000, 99, 99],
]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)

chart = openpyxl.chart.ScatterChart()
chart.legend = None
chart.x_axis.title = 'Particle size µm'
chart.x_axis.scaling.logBase = 10
chart.x_axis.scaling.min = 1
chart.x_axis.minorGridlines = openpyxl.chart.axis.ChartLines()

chart.y_axis.title = 'Cumulative mass %'
chart.y_axis.scaling.min = 0
chart.y_axis.scaling.max = 100

xvalues = openpyxl.chart.Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=8)
for i in range(2, 4):
    values = openpyxl.chart.Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=1, max_row=8)
    series = openpyxl.chart.Series(values, xvalues, title_from_data=True)
    series.smooth = True
    series.marker.symbol = "square"
    
    chart.series.append(series)

ws.add_chart(chart, "A10")

wb.save("scatter.xlsx")

Additional to the example this sets:

chart.x_axis.scaling
chart.x_axis.minorGridlines
chart.y_axis.scaling
series.smooth
series.marker.symbol

Result is:

